# Custom annotation with exception handler Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to get my code shorter and instead to do a lot of if I wanna use the annotation, I tried to make my annotation but it doesn't work, the code that I would like to remove all the if statement is this:

```java
public String addProduct(Product product) throws BadRequestException {
        //  log.info("product: " + product);
        List<Product> oldProducts;
        int maxLotto;
        if (!validate(product.getName()) || !validate(product.getBarCode())) {
            throw new BadRequestException("please write name or barCode");
        }
        ....
    }
```

These above just check if the string value is null or empty
I tried to make my annotation doing this:

```java
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotEmptyValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NotEmpty {
    String message() default "";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

```java
public class NotEmptyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotEmpty, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(NotEmpty notEmpty) {
    }

   
public class NotEmptyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotEmpty, String> {
String message;
    @Override
    public void initialize(NotEmpty notEmpty) {
        message= notEmpty.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String obj, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        System.out.println("annotation"+obj);
        if(obj == null || obj.trim().equals("")){
            throw  new MyException(message);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

My problem is that the annotation it doesn

Comment: It should be an `||` not an `&&`. Also there is already a `@NotEMtpy` or `@NotBlank` annotation that does this, so you wouldn't need to roll your own.

Comment: thanks for the correction on if, the problem with the orther annotations is I can't throw my custom Excemptio wih my message

Comment: Why would you need a custom exception. Add an exception handler that converts the generic spring exception to your custom exception (or rewrite your code to handle the regular exceptions). Trying to redefine all available annotations isn't really the way to go.

Comment: Nor should you actually throw an exception from there unless there is a technical error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, I m a begginer of spring so i don't know a lot of things, anyway do you know why my annotation it doesn't work? I changed the condition of the if statement

Comment: There is too little code to answer that. I would expect a missing `@Valid` on the controller. But as stated don't throw exceptions as that will actually break validation.